# Why is there an error in the general term formula of a sequence when replacing it?

Tags: differential-equations

```
First@RSolve[{a[n + 1] == (2 a[n])/(a[n] + 1), a[1] == 2/3}, a[n], n]
b[n_] = 1/a[n] - 1 /. %
```

Error prompt:
"{-1+1/a[n]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid 
dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"

Comment: On Win7-x64, v12.2.0, I get `-1 + 2^-n (1 + 2^n)` and no errors are generated.

Comment: Try `Clear["Global`*"]` or start a new kernel.